# Accessing YouTube yt:rating (like/dislike) system in PHP

Tags: php, api, youtube

I'm using PHP to access YouTube video attributes e.g. title, url, thumbnail, duration etc.

Not that gd:rating (5 star ratings) has been replaced by yt:rating (like/dislike system), I'm trying to modify my PHP.

**gd:rating (old)**

```
$gd = $entry->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');  
if ($gd->rating) {  
    $attrs = $gd->rating->attributes();  
    $rating = $attrs['average'];   
} else {  
    $rating = 0;   
}
```

**yt:rating (new)**

```
$yt = $entry->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');  
if ($yt->rating && $yt->rating[0]->attributes()) {  
    $attrs = $yt->rating[0]->attributes();  
    $videoobj[$loopCounter]['dislikes'] = strval($attrs['numDislikes']);  
    $videoobj[$loopCounter]['likes'] = strval($attrs['numLikes']);  
} else {  
    $videoobj[$loopCounter]['dislikes'] = 0;  
    $videoobj[$loopCounter]['likes'] = 0;  
}
```

Using the yt:rating code didn't work.  Even if I do a `print_r($yt->rating);`, there is nothing in the array.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correction. You can.

The URL you access needs this appended to the end:

```
    $url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $vid . '?v=2';
```

That made all the difference - so the last bit of my code:

```
// get <yt:rating> node for like/dislikes
$yt = $entry->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
$attrs = $yt->rating->attributes();
$obj->dislikes = $attrs['numDislikes'];
$obj->likes = $attrs['numLikes'];
echo $obj->dislikes;
echo ' ';
echo $obj->likes;
```

Comment: Yeah, the last bit of my code is a lot like your code - so the key is the URL you are accessing it by.